# Efficient way to know if any pixel is white in image?

Tags: python, opencv

So basically I m trying to use OpenCV-Python to do motion detection. I used [this](http://www.steinm.com/blog/motion-detection-webcam-python-opencv-differential-images/) tutorial to do so and here is my code.

```
import cv2

def diffImg(t0, t1, t2):
    d1 = cv2.absdiff(t2, t1)
    d2 = cv2.absdiff(t1, t0)
    return cv2.bitwise_and(d1, d2)


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

t = cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
tp = cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
tpp = cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

while cap.isOpened():
    img = cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img2 = diffImg(t,tp,tpp)

cv2.imshow("Motion", img2)
t=tp
tp=tpp
tpp=img

key = cv2.waitKey(10)

if key == 27 :
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    break
```

The I want to print on the console when there is a motion detection or not.
When there is a motion, there are white pixels in the input image.
But I don't know how to find white pixels  in the input image. 
Can anyone tell me how to find if there are white pixels in the image returned by diffImg or not ?

Comment: OpenCV provides countNonZero(), for example. Probably some builtin python (numpy) function is faster. Maybe "any" or "all"?

Comment: Maybe just find the brightest pixel (i.e. max) and see if that is white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look to the [`countNonZero`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero) function fom OpenCV.

Example provided by Baqir Khan:

```
if cv2.countNonZero(img2) > 29700: 
    print("Motion") 
else: 
    print("No Motion")
```

Comment: At least provide an example, or this answer should have been a comment

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :) @Miki here's the example 
`if cv2.countNonZero(img2) > 29700:
        print("Motion")
    else:
        print("No Motion")`